# Bug related to a command that only functions if a person has a certain role Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

so i've been having some trouble having this command i made that is supposed to work only if the user has a certain role, in the other case, it's supposed to tell the user that he doesn't have the required role. When I test it and I actually have the role, it works, but when I don't have the role it doesn't send the message. Here's a pcture of the log that appears when using the command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH1th.png)

Here's the code i use

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Saloon Member")
async def caca(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.send("Hi")
    except discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRole("Saloon Member"):
        await ctx.send("Lil boy doesnt have saloon member")
```

Here's another way i tried to solve the problem :

I defined a check_role that checks if the user has the role.

```
 async def check_role(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    roles = [r.name.lower() for r in member.roles]
    if not ctx.message.startswith(bot.command_prefix):
        return
    if ctx.author.bot:
        return
    if "Saloon Member" in roles:
        await ctx.channel.send("HAHAHA, you don't have the membership, #RestInPeace")
        return False
    return True
```

Here's what a command from the code looks like :

```
    @bot.command()
async def inspirobot(ctx):
    if not await check_role(ctx):
        return
    response = requests.get("http://inspirobot.me/api?generate=true")
    image_url = response.text
    await ctx.send(image_url)
```

And here is the command that gives you the role :

```
@bot.command()
async def givemembership(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Saloon Member")
    if role:
        await member.add_roles(role)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'The Saloon Member role does not exist.')
```

For some reason, everytime i use any of the commands, it simply doesn't do anything. Here's what the logs say when i use a command with the bot :
[Logs of the bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrP26.png)

Comment: The `has_role` decorator means that without the role, you can't successfully cal the command at all.

Comment: Ok, so do you know how I could make the except option work ?@CrazyChucky

Comment: The error tells you that the `Message` object has no `startswith` method. In any event, your edit seems like a new question to me.

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The way you are doing it seems correct. You have some mistakes though. `ctx.message.startswith(...)`: [startswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) is a method that has to be applied over an str object, not over a [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) object. Change it to `ctx.message.content.startswith(...)` to apply the method over the content (str) of the message.

Comment: @Jabro i did the change you suggested, but now the logs are telling me this error message : AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message'
(Reffering to ctx.message.content.startswith)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `@has_role` decorator to check if the guild member has a specific role, use the [commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) object to check if that specific role is in the role's list of the member using the command:

```
@bot.command(name="caca")
async def caca(ctx : commands.Context):
    if not ctx.guild or ctx.guild.id != 123456789: # The id of the server that has the "Saloon_Member" role
        return

    role = ctx.guild.get_role(987654321) # The "Saloon Member" role id
    if role in ctx.author.roles: await ctx.send("Hi")
    else: await ctx.send("Lil boy doesnt have saloon member")
```

Comment: Thank you but the program you sent requires it to work only in a specific server... Is there any way for it to work on any server no matter it's ID ?

Comment: So your bot is in multiple servers, each of them having a role with the same name, which is the one you want to check?

Comment: Yes. Do you think you could help me with this ?

Comment: @SorenForgeman You should mention that in your question.